# How set the different sizes image into circle?

Tags: android, api

Actually I have used many images of different sizes and I want to set all the images in circle. 
I have used `de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView` this library but problem of using this library is that image is cut from the border and I don't want to cut it.
 Can anyone help me?

Comment: you may want to change the scaleType of the image (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: just you need the image in circle shape??

Comment: i have tried but nothing happens..